# Bake isn't showing up as anything

Tags: texturing

I'm trying to make a model for a game, and I cant bake the texture. I've tried multiple "fixes" but none of them have worked for me.

My blend file is: https://www.mediafire.com/file/kz4tca59dv6m7pi/VRC+Lava.blend/file

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

I took a look in you Blend file, and I baked the diffuse color (I think that's what you did) and I got this :

[image]

[image]

It may look like something completely black but if you look closely (you may need to adjust your screen brightness to see it correctly) you can see that there's actually some color on it. And this is exactly the diffuse color of your material (it's what you get if you use only the `Principled BSDF` like so) :

[image]

[image]

But you need to understand that your material is a **mix** of an `Emission` shader and a `Principled` shader, so you will also need to **bake the emission** by doing this :

[image]

and hitting `Bake` (make sure you bake on a different image or you'll overwrite the previous bake), you'll get :

[image]

it is the direct output of your Emission shader.

If you need the image to look like your final render, you may want to chose `Combined` from the list like so (it will also bake lighting information) :

[image]

and you'll get this :

[image]

I hope this solves your problem.

As a side note, if you have multiple UV maps for the same object, you can specify what UV map you want to use for baking by pluging an `UV Map` node in the `Vector` input of your `Image` node and by selecting the UV map under the UV map section of the Object Data properties :

[image]

[image]